# Why getting error that No name servers found at child?

Tags: dns, namespaces, nameservers, reverse-dns

I have a setup that had 2 DNS servers dns3-master and dns4-slave, in that setup I was able to add reverse delegation on the ripe site, then we had added one more dns server and we made it dns5-slave to the dns3-master.

So why I am getting following errors ?

> Quote: RIPE Database Webupdates Error: RDNS Authorisation failed
>   Show the full response message 
>   - From-Host: x.x.x.
>   - Date/Time: Tue Jan 29 08:50:54 2013

```
SUMMARY OF UPDATE:
Number of objects found: 1
Number of objects processed successfully: 0
Create: 0
Modify: 0
Delete: 0
No Operation: 0
Number of objects processed with errors: 1
Create: 1
Modify: 0
Delete: 0
Syntax Errors: 0
```

DETAILED EXPLANATION:

The following object(s) were found to have ERRORS:

```
Create FAILED: [domain] x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
Info: Authorisation passed
Info: Syntax check passed

domain: x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
descr: NTT Reverse Delegation for x.x.x.0/24
nserver: dns3.ex.com
nserver: dns4.ex.com
admin-c: NRa19-RIPE
tech-c: NRa19-RIPE
zone-c: NRa19-RIPE
mnt-by: MNT-NEU
changed: xx@xx.com 20130129
source: RIPE

Info: Authorisation for parent [inetnum] x.x.x.x - x.x.x.x
using mnt-lower:
authenticated by: MNT-NEU
```

RDNS: (related to x.x.x.in-addr.arpa) ERROR:

No name servers found at child. No name servers could be found at the child. This usually means that the child is not configured to answer queries about the zone.

RDNS: (related to x.x.x.in-addr.arpa) CRITICAL:

```
Fatal error in delegation for zone x.x.x.in-addr.arpa.
```

No name servers found at child or at parent. No further testing can be performed.

```
Error: RDNS Authorization failed
```

The RIPE Database is subject to [Terms and Conditions](http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf):

> For assistance or clarification please contact: RIPE Database
>   Administration 
>        Generated by RIPE WHOIS Update version 1.51.1 on WHOIS4 Handled sync update (RIPE, LGC, 2013-01-29 08:50:54)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my above Problem by adding the reverse subnet into the DNS server so that it can respond to the query from the RIPE.

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is just not enough to actually understand what you did. Please add the actual zone files you used, both forward and reverse, as well as a description of what you were trying to do, and the steps you went through.

Answer (score 1):

As I found this solution resolutive also for me, I would like to add a detailed explanation:

Under each x.x.x.in-addr.arpa zone you must create NS records pointing to your name servers.

When RIPE is doing a check before allowing you to create the PTR record, it would like to find  NS records pointing to your nameservers.

If NS records are not configured you will receive a ***ERROR: No name servers found at child.

I hope it may help other persons.

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is just not enough to actually understand what you did.  Please add the actual zone files you used, both forward and reverse, as well as a description of what you were trying to do, and the steps you went through.

Answer (score 0):

The x.x.x.in-addr.arpa zone should have at least 2 NS records.
Both of those records or are in the same subnet x.x.x or have a correct reverse dns record.